# Installing Fedora along side Ubuntu

Tags: partition, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 by specifying "Use the entire disk" during installation. Now, I would like to install Fedora alongside Ubuntu. I would like to know whether it's possible or not. If it's possible, then please explain the procedure to me.

[image]

Can you tell me which option to choose and what should I do from here on?

Comment: `Shrink current system`. The instructions should be clear enough from there.

Comment: I've had success with the shrink partition option in Fedora, but it can cause glitches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your installer, at the partitioning stage:

- Resize your Ubuntu partition to something smaller; a decent partitioner will tell you the limits in which you can do this. For example if the data in a 100GB Ubuntu partition is taking 80GB, you cannot resize it to a smaller size than that.
- Create a fresh partition in the empty space, and install Fedora there.
- Continue with installation as normal.

Were I you, I'd let both Fedora and Ubuntu share a `/home` partition, and give each around 20GB partition each. This is just to simplify the set up, and shouldn't cause issues if you follow [these guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6344/688).

Comment: This is what I love about Linux; you can resize partitions without getting boot errors (**cough** windows **cough**).