# Share Home Directory between Arch and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, dual-boot

Before I start asking my question, I would like you to know that I am aware of the ["Different linux distros sharing the same /home folder?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/different-linux-distros-sharing-the-same-home-folder) question already asked on this website. It did not quite answer my question though, and as it's too broad I don't think it ever will.

Is it possible to share the user directory between Ubuntu and Arch, and how to make that work? I'm talking about what's known as `~`.

I already have Ubuntu installed, but I am really annoyed by outdated packages. I would like to run them next to each other so when I need to use new software I can use ArchLinux. I could just switch completely to ArchLinux, but I don't want to take any risks. (Maybe I'll hate it)

Just as a sidenote, my /home is on a different partition, but my users' directories also encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

No problem. This is the easiest to do if home is a separate partition, but in any case, it can be done. Just put the mount in your fstab (regular mount if it is a partition, `mount --bind` if it is a subdirectory on another mounted hard drive).

The only catch is, all the users need to have the same uid's, otherwise the ownership will be wrong.

Comment: How to fix the user IDs? Will it work if my home directories are encrypted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248056/change-user-id-in-linux

Encryption just means you need to do the same thing you did in the other installation to decrypt it.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problem:

1. `usernames` and `groupnames` store with `UIDs` and `GUIDs` suppose you have username `joe` with id 1000 on ubuntu machine, and username joe has been stored with 1003 on `Arch` machine.
2. some dot files contains some configuration files , you have separate version of application on  two machines.

Comment: I only just realized, I also have my /home encrypted, so I'm guessing this is a no-go.

Comment: encryption shouldn't be a problem, it doesn't depend on the os but the credentials and key/passwords that can be transferred or reinitialized.

Comment: You only just syncronize /etc/passwd and /etc/groups.

Comment: Exactly. You can clone (copy or just mount --bind) the /etc/{passwd, group, shadow, gshadow} between distributions if they really have the same groups and users. If there are features specific to the distribution, just copy the relevant lines.

Comment: Config files shouldn't be a problem, it's rare that the config becomes incompatible.

Comment: +orion I'm guessing I could just partition the /etc/ and the /home/ in one partition, and use the same one for both distributions, and it'll work fine? I know it might have some problems with updated software as /etc/ is where the configuration files go, but surely a program doesn't just error on abundant lines.