# Can i use the same /home partition for multiple distro's partitons

Tags: partition, dual-boot, home, distributions, shared-partition

Hello Unix/Linux Stackexchange. I have a mulri-part question about the `/home` partition. Thanks for taking the time to read and reply to all the questions below.

Is it possible to share the `/home` partition with two or more separate Linux partitions? For example can I use the same `/home` partition with an `/Arch` and `/Debian` partition?

If it is possible can I also use the same `username` for both or is it better to use different ones and share data between them?

I am also assuming that in this setup I would also need a separate `/boot` partition as well  is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to share the /home partition with two or more separate
>   Linux partitions? For example can I use the same /home partition with
>   an /Arch and /Debian partition?

Yep typically not an issue.

> If it is possible can I also use the same username for both or is it
>   better to use different ones and share data between them?

Yep, you'll want to make sure they have the same UID as and GID as well most likely.

> I am also assuming that in this setup I would also need a separate
>   /boot partition as well  is that correct?

Nope, you just need a separate kernel, and initramfs in /boot and a separate root and other non shared mounts.  As well as entries in the boot manager for both OSs

You'll also want to be careful about libraries compiled/created in the shared home that might use different versions because of the different software available in each OS.

Comment: If the OP has version X of a package for Arch and version Y of that package for their Debian version, and the configurations for X and Y are necessarily different, won't that be problematic, as noted in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/different-linux-distros-sharing-the-same-home-folder ? I think you need to make note of that hazard.

Comment: If the configuration is stored in the home dir sure, but most applications don’t just error or crash when fed old configuration files and it’s not really an obstacle to achieving a shared home.

Comment: Those symlinks seem like a giant pain. I’m not sure what you’d be trying to accomplish with them.